# webpack-dev-server will not work on Windows due to its dependency on node-gyp

Tags: node.js, windows, build, node-gyp, webpack-dev-server

I need to ask if webpack-dev-server's dependency on node-gyp is absolutely necessary?
node-gyp is a nightmare for many node developers that develop on a windows machine.
it needs a C++ compiler which forces you to download visual studio and all sorts of service packs that got nothing to do with node development. in our case - after a 1.6 Gigs of installations and dependencies we were still unable to make node-gyp work on windows...
Why would webpack-dev-server however need node-gyp as a dependency?
As far as I know it has an express http server with socket.io... the webpack package alone doesn't require node-gyp, so why the webpack-dev-server need it?
Can you let it go? it creates a lot of unnecessary pain for developers...
Anyone here have any idea why node-gyp is essential to webpack-dev-server?
Can this dependency be removed?
It is well known that node-gyp is a real pain for developers using windows...
It seems like the dependency is used by bufferutil in engin.io in socket.io...
\webpack-dev-server\socket.io\engine.io\ws\bufferutil
Is there a work-around?

[image: This is what a simple install of webpack-dev-server looks on windows...]